# Iterate over an array in javascript and concat it to another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have an array in javascript. I have to iterate over it and concat the values to a variable and each value should be separated by comma.

This is my code:

```
var selected = new Array();
jQuery("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    selected.push(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var a = new Array("Wind","Rain","Fire");
var myVar1 = a.join();      // assigns "Wind,Rain,Fire" to myVar1
var myVar2 = a.join(", ");  // assigns "Wind, Rain, Fire" to myVar2
var myVar3 = a.join(" + "); // assigns "Wind + Rain + Fire" to myVar3
```

#### Issues:

It wont work with arguments because the arguments object is not an array, although it looks like it. It has no join method:

```
function myFun(arr) {
   return 'the list: ' + arr.join(",");
} 
myFun(arrayObject);
```

will throw

`TypeError: arr.join is not a function`

because `arr` is not a jQuery object, just a regular JavaScript object.

Comment: var myVar2 = a.join(", "); is joining my values separated by a ,  Thank u Zaheer..!

Comment: Your answer doesn't show how to combine this with the `$.each` used by OP.

Answer (score 4):

```
selected.join(',')
```

see [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Where I have to use selected.join(',')?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code.

```
var namesArray = new Array("John", "Micheal", "Doe","Steve","Bob"); //array
var resultString = ""; // result variable

//iterate each item of array
for (var i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) 
     resultString += namesArray[i] + ",";

//remove the extra comma at the end, using a regex
resultString = resultString.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '')

alert(resultString);
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

OR, rather than have to remove the extra comma, add the final element outside of the for loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < namesArray.length-1; i++)
    resultString += namesArray[i] + ", ";
resultString += namesArray[namesArray.length-1];
```

Yes, I know this is an old post :-)